# Access parent magic method from trait

Tags: php, traits, magic-methods

I'm trying to redefine the behaviour of the magic method `__set` in a trait. The problem shows up when I also want to access from the trait to the parent class custom `__set` function.

```
trait TestingTrait {


    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        // Some stuff...

        parent::__set($key, $value);
        // self::__set($key, $value);
    }

}

class TestingClass {

    use TestingTrait;

}

$var = new TestingClass();
$var->value = 'some value';
```

Everything works perfect until I need to also use the main class `__set` method as it's doing some other stuff with the variable sets.

I've tried with `self` but it goes into an infinite loop. Is there any way to access the main class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use `$this->` like this:

```
<?php

trait TestingTrait {


    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        // Some stuff...
        $this->$key = 'proof that it is going through here: ' . $value;
    }

}

class TestingClass {

    use TestingTrait;

}

$var = new TestingClass();
$var->value = 'some value';

echo $var->value;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/8b16ea2264ca8d):

```
proof that it is going through here: some value
```

Comment: It actually works, however it does not call the main class ***__set*** method, just sets the property.

Comment: No. And I emphasized that it does call the `__set`, because it prepends the value `proof that it is going through here: `.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know traits behaviour is as if it were a portion of code literally copy/pasted into the class.

[PHP: Traits (Example 2)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

It's not possible to access the main class via parent as it actually have no parent extending from.